# Solving a difficult equation for a variable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, applied-mathematics, matrix-equations

I'm trying to obtain the maximum likelihood estimate of the parameters for a model I'm building. I have constants $\sigma$, $\mu$, and $q_0$; a boolean matrix $\alpha$; and vectors $A, \beta, r, d,$ and $Q$, all quantities non-negative. I set the derivative of the log likelihood function equal to zero with

$$0=\sum_j \alpha_{kj} \Bigg[ \beta_j r_j \frac{\ln (A_j - r_j\sum_i \alpha_{ij} Q_i) + \sigma^2 - \mu}{\sigma^2 (A_j - r_j\sum_i \alpha_{ij} Q_i)} + (1-\beta_j)\frac{\ln(1-d_j)}{q_0} \Bigg]$$

How can I solve for $Q$?

Comment: You probably should provide some context and motivation for this. To my presumably inexperienced eyes for the area you're working on, this expression looks like a scary beast. Where does it come from?

Comment: I'm building a statistical model and trying to obtain the maximum likelihood estimate of its parameters. This is the derivative of the log likelihood function set equal to zero. I considered posting to CrossValidated but, although the motivation is statistical, the solution seems to me to be purely algebraic. You are right that it's a scary beast.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the question you have asked may not actually be the one that you wanted to ask.  However, I will answer it anyway.  Your equation contains the expression
$$ \alpha_{kj}Q_k + \sum_{i\neq k} \alpha_{ij} Q_i $$
but this is just the same as $\sum_i\alpha_{ij}Q_j$.  It therefore does not depend on $k$; I will call it $u_j$.  I will then put 
$$ v_j = \frac{\ln(A_j-r_ju_j)+\sigma^2-\mu}{\sigma^2(A_j-r_ju_j)} $$ 
and
$$ w_j = \beta_jv_j + (1-\beta_j)\frac{\ln(1-d_j)}{q_0}. $$
Your equation is then $\sum_j\alpha_{kj}w_j=0$.  Presumably this is supposed to hold for all $k$.  It is now a purely linear problem to find the possible vectors $w$, and another linear problem with the same matrix to recover the vector $Q$ from the vector $u$.  It sounds like you believe that there should be a unique solution for $Q$.  That can only happen if the matrix $\alpha$ has trivial kernel, so $w$ would have to be zero.  From there it is trivial to find $v$, then $u_j$ can be expressed in terms of $v_j$ using the Lambert W function, and finally it is a linear problem to find $Q$.

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful. You said it's "another linear problem with the same matrix to recover the vector Q from the vector u" but it's not clear to me what this linear problem would look like. Could you spell it out for me please? (P.S. I don't necessarily expect a unique solution, but thanks for those clarifying details.)

Comment: Also why do you suspect that this question is not the one I wanted to ask?